# Quantidade do produto aumentando conforme atualiza a pagina

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou com um problema que sempre que dou f5 a quantidade do produto aumenta... gostaria que quando atualizasse ele não subisse esse índice caso o usuário não clicasse em comprar mais.

```
}
if(isset($_GET['add']) && $_GET['add'] == "carrinho"){
$idProduto = $_GET['id'];
if(!isset($_SESSION['itens'][$idProduto]))
{
    $_SESSION['itens'][$idProduto] = 1;
}else {
    $_SESSION['itens'][$idProduto] += 1;
}
}
  if(count($_SESSION['itens'])==0){
echo 'Carrinho Vazio<br><a href="cardapio.php">Adicionar itens<a/>';
}else{
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'restaurante';
try {
$conexao = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database;charset=utf8", 
$username, $password,
array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));

 }
 catch(PDOException $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
 }                  
foreach($_SESSION['itens'] as $idProduto => $quantidade){
$select = $conexao-> prepare("SELECT * FROM produto WHERE id=?");
$select -> bindParam(1,$idProduto);
$select -> execute();
$produtos =$select ->fetchAll();
    $total = $quantidade * $produtos[0]['Preco_produto'];
    echo  
        $produtos[0]['Nome_produto'].'&nbsp <br/>
        Preço:'.number_format($produtos[0] 
     ['Preco_produto'],2,",",".").'<br/>
        Quantidade: '.$quantidade.'<br/>
    Total : '.number_format($total,2,",",".").'
        <a href="remover.php?remover=carrinho&id='.$idProduto.'">Remover</a>
        <hr>';

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No início do seu código caso o `$idProduto` exista na sessão você está incrementando ele, apenas remova isso.

**De**

```php
if(!isset($_SESSION['itens'][$idProduto]))
{
    $_SESSION['itens'][$idProduto] = 1;
}else {
    $_SESSION['itens'][$idProduto] += 1;
}
```

**Para**

```php
if(!isset($_SESSION['itens'][$idProduto]))
{
    $_SESSION['itens'][$idProduto] = 1;
}
```